# http 404 error in j_security_check

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, j-security-check

I am stuck with this persistent error while creating my spring 4 app. Here's my code:

**Initializer.java:**

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    // I have tried adding the following but it doesn't seem to work also:
    @Override
     protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Filter[] { new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain") };
    }
}
```

**WebAppConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.myco.controller")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**RootConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RootConfig {
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
 private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Resource
private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
}

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;  
}

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sec/moderation.html").hasRole("MODERATOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user-login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/success-login.html")
            .failureUrl("/error-login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html");
    }

}
```

**And lastly, my login jsp (login-form.jsp):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Login page</title>
<style>
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login page</h1>

<p>
<c:if test="${error == true}">
    <b class="error">Invalid login or password.</b>
</c:if>
</p>

<form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" >
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Login:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"size="30" maxlength="40"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" size="30" maxlength="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form> 

<p>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html">Home page</a><br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My error:

[image]

Comment: What is the spring security's version?

Comment: Pls read, I am using Spring 4, it's stated above.

Comment: I was asking about [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) its version is different from core spring.

Comment: oh. spring security's 3.2.5. Sorry didn't read properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security 3.2 the login url is changed to `/login` from `/j_spring_security_check` also the username and password paremeters are changed.

username : from `j_username` to `username`

password  : from `j_password` to `password`

So your form will be.

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='login'/>" >
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Login:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"size="30" maxlength="40"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" maxlength="32" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```